# JS to keep active state of menu in relation to iFrame content

Tags: javascript, css

I know that to get a link to display current page state using CSS I would have to create new pages, but I would rather not reload the menu and use an iframe.  So how can I keep my menu buttons with the current page active state in relation to the corresponding page in the iframe?

How do I attach a set of behaviors to the links on load of the window?

Any help is appreciated!
THANKs

Answer (score 0):

This post discusses how to attach events to communicate between the parent site and the iFrame. http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-domain-iframe-communication-without-location-polling

However, you MUST be loading the iFrame resource from the same domain as your parent site and have control over the scripts loading on that page. Otherwise it falls into the cross-domain request category and it would be difficult to accomplish this. This limitation is by design as it would present major security issues.

Comment: This is not completely true: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.postMessage